# Como capturar um evento em um stub? [vue-test-utils]

Tags: vue.js, jest

Estou tentando testar um evento semelhante a esse:

```
// template: <form @submit.prevent="save"></form>
const save = jest.fn()
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {methods: { save }})
wrapper.find('form').trigger('submit.prevent')
expect(save).toBeCalled() // Sucesso
```

Este evento invoca um método no componente e isso funciona muito bem.

Mas se eu usar um componente customizado, o método não é chamado

```
// template: <my-custom-form @submit="save"></my-custom-form>
const save = jest.fn()
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {methods: { save }, stubs: ['my-custom-form']})
wrapper.find('my-custom-form-stub').trigger('submit')
expect(save).toBeCalled() // Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
```

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Dessa maneira resolveu o problema

```
<my-custom-form @submit.native.prevent="save"></my-custom-form>
```

[Link de referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53447753/3797668)